# Databricks SQL: Why is subquery in left join causing error msg

Tags: databricks

I am attempting to use a subquery in a left join condition, but am getting an error message that reads: `"Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: TableD;"` and points to the `FROM TableD D2` statement in my subquery.

```
SELECT D1.Code, D1.Description, C.InstanceKey
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON B.DetailKey = C.DetailKey
LEFT JOIN TableD D1
    ON C.InstanceKey = D1.InstanceKey
    AND D1.RankCnt = (SELECT MIN(D2.RankCnt) 
                      FROM TableD D2
                      WHERE C.InstanceKey = D2.InstanceKey);
```

If I remove the subquery and hardcode `D1.RankCnt = [anyValidRankCnt]`, the query runs without issue.

This question has also been posted on the Databricks Community Forum at https://forums.databricks.com/questions/14588/why-is-subquery-in-left-join-causing-error-msg.html.

Comment: last join in your query expects a column name for the left join. whats the output of `SELECT MIN(D2.RankCnt) FROM TableD D2  WHERE C.InstanceKey = D2.InstanceKey)` subquery??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that particular type of [correlated subquery](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2728434780191932/1483312212640900/6987336228780374/latest.html) is supported in Spark at this time, although I was able to rewrite it in a couple of different ways, including using `ROW_NUMBER`.  Please check these queries are semantically equivalent to yours with your data:

```
%sql
-- Rewrite 1: CTE
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT D1.Code, D1.Description, C.InstanceKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY c.InstanceKey ORDER BY D1.RankCnt ) xrank
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON B.DetailKey = C.DetailKey
LEFT JOIN TableD D1
    ON C.InstanceKey = D1.InstanceKey
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE xrank = 1


-- Rewrite 2: subquery
SELECT x.Code, x.Description, C.InstanceKey
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON B.DetailKey = C.DetailKey
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT D1.InstanceKey, D1.Code, D1.Description, D1.RankCnt
    FROM TableD D1
        INNER JOIN
            ( 
            SELECT InstanceKey, MIN(RankCnt) RankCnt
            FROM TableD 
            GROUP BY InstanceKey
            ) D2 ON D1.InstanceKey = D2.InstanceKey
            AND D1.RankCnt = D2.RankCnt
    ) x
    ON c.InstanceKey = x.InstanceKey;


-- Rewrite 3: UNION ALL
SELECT D1.Code, D1.Description, C.InstanceKey
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON B.DetailKey = C.DetailKey
INNER JOIN TableD D1
    ON C.InstanceKey = D1.InstanceKey
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT D2.InstanceKey, MIN(D2.RankCnt) RankCnt
        FROM TableD D2
        GROUP BY D2.InstanceKey
        ) x ON C.InstanceKey = x.InstanceKey
        AND D1.RankCnt = x.RankCnt

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS Code, NULL AS Description, C.InstanceKey
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON B.DetailKey = C.DetailKey
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableD D1
    WHERE C.InstanceKey = D1.InstanceKey
    );
```